# Double-click editing of NSTableView columns headers

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

Is it possible to change the names of NSTableView columns by double clicking on the columns headers? Any suggestions on the best way to do this.

I am trying:

1. Set the double action of the table view to call a custom method on the double click
2. Try and edit the NSTableHeaderCell instance by calling `editWithFrame:inView:editor:delegate:event:`.

I'm not entirely sure why this distorts the text, but when you double click the header it makes the text look like this, no field editor appears,

[image: editWithFrame:inView:editor:delegate:event: on an NSTableHeaderCell]

In the AppDelegate,

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    ...
    [_tableView setDoubleAction:@selector(doubleClickInTableView:)];
    ...
}

-(void) doubleClickInTableView:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger row = [_tableView clickedRow];
    NSInteger column = [_tableView clickedColumn];
    if(row == -1){
        /* Want to edit the column header on double-click */
        NSTableColumn *tableColumn = [[_tableView tableColumns] objectAtIndex:column];
        NSTableHeaderView *headerView = [_tableView headerView];
        NSTableHeaderCell *headerCell = [tableColumn headerCell];
        NSRect cellFrame = [headerView headerRectOfColumn:column];
        NSText * fieldEditor = [[headerView window] fieldEditor:YES forObject:nil];
        [headerCell editWithFrame:cellFrame inView:headerView editor:fieldEditor delegate:headerCell event:nil];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it seems doable
what you see in your screenshot is the window's field editor overlaying your cell's textfield
the editor has a transparent background so that's why it's messed up

so here's the deal :

you will need to have your own NSTableHeaderCell subclass to act as the field editor's delegate :

```
@interface NBETableHeaderCell () <NSTextViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation NBETableHeaderCell

- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSTextView *editor = notification.object;
    // Update the title, kill the focus ring, end editing
    [self setTitle:editor.string];
    [self setHighlighted:NO];
    [self endEditing:editor];
}

- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    if([self isHighlighted])
    {
        [self drawFocusRingMaskWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView.superview];
    }

    [super drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
}

- (void)drawFocusRingMaskWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    [controlView lockFocus];
    NSSetFocusRingStyle(NSFocusRingOnly);
    [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:cellFrame] fill];
    [controlView unlockFocus];
}

@end
```

in the app delegate's awakeFromNib don't forget to set the NSTableHeaderCell to **Editable** !

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSTableColumn *newCol = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"whatever"];

    NBETableHeaderCell *hc = [[NBETableHeaderCell alloc] initTextCell:@"Default header text"];
    [hc setEditable:YES];
    [hc setUsesSingleLineMode:YES];
    [hc setScrollable:NO];
    [hc setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
    [newCol setHeaderCell:hc];

    [self.tableView addTableColumn:newCol];
    [self.tableView setDoubleAction:@selector(doubleClickInTableView:)];
}
```

for the rest, you were nearly there
*after* calling selectWithFrame, we customize the editor to have a nice white opaque background,
so that we don't see the textview beneath it
as for the focus ring : it is the cell's job,
we just set the cell in highlighted state so it knows it has to draw the ring now

```
- (void)doubleClickInTableView:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger row = [_tableView clickedRow];
    NSInteger column = [_tableView clickedColumn];

    if(row == -1&& column >= 0)
    {
        NSTableColumn *tableColumn = [[_tableView tableColumns] objectAtIndex:column];
        NSTableHeaderView *headerView = [_tableView headerView];
        NBETableHeaderCell *headerCell = [tableColumn headerCell];

        // cellEditor is basically a unique NSTextView shared by the window
        // that adjusts its style to the field calling him
        // it stands above the text field's view giving the illusion that you are editing it
        // and if it has no background you will see the editor's NSTextView overlaying the TextField
        // wich is why you have that nasty bold text effect in your screenshot
        id cellEditor = [self.window fieldEditor:YES forObject:self.tableView];

        [headerCell setHighlighted:YES];
        [headerCell selectWithFrame:[headerView headerRectOfColumn:column]
                             inView:headerView
                             editor:cellEditor
                           delegate:headerCell
                              start:0
                             length:headerCell.stringValue.length];

        [cellEditor setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
        [cellEditor setDrawsBackground:YES];
    }
}
```

some more info about the field editor here : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/UsingWindowFieldEditor.html

the only thing missing now to make it complete is that the field editor's frame won't update if you resize the cell while editing…

Comment: Thank you for such an elegant solution!

Comment: Oops, first bounty, I didn't realise I had to press the 50+ button!

Answer (score 3):

This bugged me, too, so I created a sample project and [uploaded it to GitHub.](https://github.com/DivineDominion/Editable-NSTableView-Header)

As @ben-rhayader pointed out, it's all about positioning the field editor above the header view cell.

## Double click handling

Here's the stuff we already know about in Swift.

### Window controller / custom table view controller

The interesting part in the view controller is editing the header on double click. To make that happen,

- put a `TableWindowController` (or your view controller) instance as an object in your Nib,
- add a `@IBAction func tableViewDoubleClick(sender: NSTableView)` or similar,
- connect the `NSTableView`'s `doubleAction` method to `tableViewDoubleClick`.

Editing cells is straightforward. Editing columns headers not so much.

- Header rows have a row value of -1
- to position the field editor, you need the column header frame and the field editor itself.

Part of the result:

```
extension TableWindowController {

    @IBAction func tableViewDoubleClick(sender: NSTableView) {

        let column = sender.clickedColumn
        let row = sender.clickedRow

        guard column > -1 else { return }

        if row == -1 {
            editColumnHeader(tableView: sender, column: column)
            return
        }

        editCell(tableView: sender, column: column, row: row)
    }

    private func editColumnHeader(tableView tableView: NSTableView, column: Int) {

        guard column > -1,
            let tableColumn = tableView.tableColumn(column: column),
            headerView = tableView.headerView as? TableHeaderView,
            headerCell = tableColumn.headerCell as? TableHeaderCell,
            fieldEditor = fieldEditor(object: headerView)
            else { return }

        headerCell.edit(
            fieldEditor: fieldEditor,
            frame: headerView.paddedHeaderRect(column: column),
            headerView: headerView)
    }

    private func editCell(tableView tableView: NSTableView, column: Int, row: Int) {

        guard row > -1 && column > -1,
            let view = tableView.viewAtColumn(column, row: row, makeIfNecessary: true) as? NSTableCellView
            else { return }

        view.textField?.selectText(self)
    }

    /// Convenience accessor to the `window`s field editor.
    func fieldEditor(object object: AnyObject?) -> NSText? {
        return self.window?.fieldEditor(true, forObject: object)
    }
}
```

### Custom header view and header view cells

Positioning the field editor properly is a bit of work. I put it into a `NSTableHeaderView` subclass:

```
class TableHeaderView: NSTableHeaderView {

    /// Trial and error result of the text frame that fits.
    struct Padding {
        static let Vertical: CGFloat = 4
        static let Right: CGFloat = 1
    }

    /// By default, the field editor will be very high and thus look weird.
    /// This scales the header rect down a bit so the field editor is put
    /// truly in place.
    func paddedHeaderRect(column column: Int) -> NSRect {

        let paddedVertical = CGRectInset(self.headerRectOfColumn(column), 0, Padding.Vertical)
        let paddedRight = CGRect(
            origin: paddedVertical.origin,
            size: CGSize(width: paddedVertical.width - Padding.Right, height: paddedVertical.height))

        return paddedRight
    }
}
```

That takes care of positioning the field editor. Now *using* it from the double click handler from above:

```
class TableHeaderCell: NSTableHeaderCell, NSTextViewDelegate {

    func edit(fieldEditor fieldEditor: NSText, frame: NSRect, headerView: NSView) {

        let endOfText = (self.stringValue as NSString).length
        self.highlighted = true
        self.selectWithFrame(frame,
            inView: headerView,
            editor: fieldEditor,
            delegate: self,
            start: endOfText,
            length: 0)

        fieldEditor.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor()
        fieldEditor.drawsBackground = true
    }

    func textDidEndEditing(notification: NSNotification) {

        guard let editor = notification.object as? NSText else { return }

        self.title = editor.string ?? ""
        self.highlighted = false
        self.endEditing(editor)
    }
}
```

## How to "end editing" when user double-clicks in another header cell?

The problem: the field editor is reused and merely re-positioned when a user double-clicks into another header cell. `textDidEndEditing` will not be called. The new value will not be saved.

@triple.s and @boyfarrell discussed this but without code -- I find the easiest way to know when the field editor will change is to highjack construction of the field editor and call `endEditing` manually.

```
class HeaderFieldEditor: NSTextView {

    func switchEditingTarget() {

        guard let cell = self.delegate as? NSCell else { return }

        cell.endEditing(self)
    }
}
```

Using this custom field editor when necessary:

```
class TableWindowController: NSWindowDelegate {

    func windowWillReturnFieldEditor(sender: NSWindow, toObject client: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {

        // Return default field editor for everything not in the header.
        guard client is TableHeaderView else { return nil }

        // Comment out this line to see what happens by default: the old header
        // is not deselected.
        headerFieldEditor.switchEditingTarget()

        return headerFieldEditor
    }

    lazy var headerFieldEditor: HeaderFieldEditor = {
        let editor = HeaderFieldEditor()
        editor.fieldEditor = true
        return editor
    }()
}
```

Works like a charm.

Project on GitHub: https://github.com/DivineDominion/Editable-NSTableView-Header

Answer (score 1):

@BenRhayader -- This solution is working only if i change the column header text and do a tab out so that `controlTextDidEndEditing` delegate is called. But if I change the header column text of one column and click on other column(instead of doing a tab out) , the old text is being retained i.e. the new text is not reflecting. This may be because the logic to change the text is written inside `controlTextDidEndEditing`, which is only called when a tab out is done.

Comment: It's true, I noticed this too. I fixed it in a slighly hack0ish way. I added an instance variable to the subclass of NSTableHeaderCell which saves the field editor instance when the text is being edited. If I detect a change of focus (e.g. tab out, as you suggested) then I can end the editing my calling `-endEditing:` on the cell and passing in the saved field editor. I suppose it is not too hackish, but could probably be improved.

Comment: @BenRhayader - Hi, I have added a instance variable`NSTextView *myEditor;` and setting its initial value in `controlTextDidEndEditing`. Now, if I change the header column(without tabbing out), where would I set this value so that text would be reflected in the column header.

Comment: Yes, that's good. I'm not too sure how I solved this problem now. It was a while ago. I need to check my code, I will put something on github, but I don't have much time and it could a week or so...

Comment: Solved the issue in another answer, see below. (Or above. It depends :))

Answer (score 0):

You question was answered negative here: [Making NSTableView column headers editable](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/218973-making-nstableview-column-headers-editable.html)

Comment: Thank you I hadn't found that in my previous searches. Basically I am after the same functionality as when you name a column header using interface builder; one simply double clicks the header and names it!

Comment: @boyfarrell - if it is what you need - you can give me a bounty ))

Comment: Nice try. It _is_ possible and I want to find out how. I thank you for helping, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @boyfarrell - its not "nice try". If it possible - than its not an answer. I mean its an answer if it is not possible. – MikroDel